# SQL sum of all records and latest record of each user

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
id   memberId     memberType    points      date
---- ------------ ------------- ----------- ------------
1    1001         type1         5.5         01/01/2015
2    1002         type2         4.2         01/02/2015
3    1002         type2         2.1         01/15/2015
4    1001         type2         1.5         01/15/2015
5    1002         type1         3.6         01/17/2015
```

I need to make an SQL view that will show the sum of points for each memberId and their latest memberType like below:

```
memberId    Type           totalPoints
----------- -------------- -----------
1001        type2          7.0
1002        type1          9.9
```

I tried the query below:

```
SELECT memberId, MAX(memberType) as Type, SUM(points) as totalPoints
FROM dbo.PointsEarning
GROUP BY memberId
```

But of course this only works if the latest type is the max type. Plus some of my membertypes are purely alpha. I would appreciate if anyone can provide the most efficient way of doing this since I will be using it for a table with almost 30M records.

Comment: this query works fine as per your data but where you are facing problem ?

Comment: Using MAX to get the memberType returns the wrong data for member 1002 as his latest memberType should be type2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub-query with `OVER` clauses in following:

```
SELECT memberId, 
       memberType AS Type, 
       points AS totalPoints
FROM (SELECT memberId, 
             memberType, 
             date,
             SUM(points) OVER(PARTITION BY memberId) points,                 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY memberId ORDER BY date DESC) rn
      FROM dbo.PointsEarning
)x
WHERE rn = 1
```

You can test It at <kbd>**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b033cf/1)**</kbd>

Comment: why do you have group by ? It doesn't do anything

Comment: @t-clausen.dk forgot to remove It, before I've tried to suggest another solution and kept by mistake, removed It.

Comment: Thanks! It worked although the query took almost 5 minutes to finish.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT
    SUM(points) OVER (PARTITION BY memberId) totalPoints,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY memberId ORDER BY [date] DESC) rn,
    id, memberId, memberType, points, [date]
  FROM yourtable
)
SELECT
  * 
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

After our conversation in the comments, assuming nobody ever inserts values manually to your id column (using `set identity insert`) then you can use it to find the last record. so instead of `max(date)` just use `max(id)`:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT memberId, MAX(id) as LastId, SUM(points) as totalPoints
    FROM dbo.PointsEarning
    GROUP BY memberId
)

SELECT cte.memberId, p.memberType, cte.totalPoints
FROM dbo.PointsEarning p
INNER JOIN cte ON(p.Id = cte.Id)
```

**Note:** This should provide a single record for each member, and should probably work faster then the first version (if id is actually the clustered index of the table).

### First version

One way to do it is to use a common table expression:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT memberId, MAX(date) as LastDate, SUM(points) as totalPoints
    FROM dbo.PointsEarning
    GROUP BY memberId
)

SELECT memberId, memberType, totalPoints
FROM dbo.PointsEarning p
INNER JOIN cte ON(p.memberId = cte.memberId AND p.date = cte.LastDate)
```

**Note:** Code was written directly here and not tested. there might be some mistakes.

Comment: Among the answers given this actually run the fastest but returned multiple rows for each member. My actual data involves multiple transactions per date for each member.

Comment: I suppose adding distinct to the second query will get rid of the multiple rows, but will probably make it work much slower...

Comment: Yes. I actually tried using distinct but some members still returned multiple rows because they have transactions with different memberType in a single date.

Comment: well, in that case, how can you tell which one is the latest? both Stanislovas Kalašnikovas and t-clausen.dk did not address this issue, so the queries they suggested (that are basically the same) might return different results for each time you run them on users that have multiple member types for the latest date. If that's not a problem for you then fine, but if it is, then you should figure out how to distinguish between them.

Comment: By using the identity key. I changed 'ORDER BY date DESC' to 'ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC'. I'm still figuring out how to do the same for your query,

Comment: The last line of this updated SQL should be `INNER JOIN cte ON(p.Id = cte.LastId)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.memberId,
    (SELECT p2.memberType
    FROM  PointsEarning p2
    WHERE p.memberid = p2.memberid
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 'NEXT'
        FROM PointsEarning p3
        WHERE p3.memberid = p2.memberid
        AND p3.date > p2.date)
    ) as Type, SUM(p.points) as totalPoints
FROM dbo.PointsEarning p
GROUP BY p.memberId
```

Comment: You have a mistake in the second sub query -> p3.date > p3.date should be p2.date > p3.date. However I suspect that 2 sub queries will cause a big performance hit. it's possible to do it with a single sub query, but I think the cte wi probably have better performance.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Thanks, I've fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that for every group you want to select the `memberType` of the last `date`in that group. You could use a subselect for this:

```
SELECT 
   memberId, 
   (SELECT TOP 1 memberType from PointsEarning p 
        WHERE p.memberId = PointsEarning.memberId ORDER BY date desc) as Type,
   SUM(points) as totalPoints
FROM dbo.PointsEarning
GROUP BY memberId
```